# Passing json list to MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to submit this with Ajax to a MVC3 controller:

```
    var params = {
        'productId': productId,
        'list': []
    };

    $.each($('.specificationId'), function () {
        var specId = $(this).attr('id').replace('specification_', '');

        var specification = {
            specificationId: specId,
            articleId: $('#articleid_' + specId).attr('value'),
            price: $('#price_' + specId).attr('value'),
            stock: $('#stock_' + specId).attr('value'),
            stockCount: $('#stockcount_' + specId).attr('value'),
            weight: $('#weight_' + specId).attr('value'),
            visible: $('#visible_' + specId).attr('checked')
        };

        params.list.add(specification);
    });

    console.log(params);
    //all values are parsed fine here, shows an array with json objects

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/Product/Save/",
        data: params,
        success: function () { alert('done'); }
    });
```

Now this has to go to the controller like so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Boolean Save(Int32 productId, Object[] specifications)
    {

        return true;
    }
```

But Object[] does not work, returns null, I tried all sorts of stuff like lists of a model etc, but it will stay null.

How to tackle this?

Comment: I see this is old, but for others, it might have to do with the fact that arrays need to be passed in with the `traditional` flag set to true. I ran into this again last night: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017811/form-encoded-javascript-int-not-picked-up-by-model-binder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3 includes built-in JSON model binding.

So create simple POCOs which matches the JSON your attempting to submit:

```
public class ProductJsonModel
{
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public ProductSpecificationJsonModel[] @List { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSpecificationJsonModel
{
   public int SpecificationId { get; set; }
   public int ArticleId { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }
   public int Stock { get; set; }
   public int StockCount { get; set; }
   public int Weight { get; set; }
   public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

Then accept that in your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public Boolean Save(ProductJsonModel model)
```

As long as the property names in the JSON object match the property names in the POCO's, MVC will bind for you.

Also - you should serialise the JSON using `.stringify` or something similar, and set the `contentType` of the `$.ajax` object accordingly.

Comment: This is what I expect to work, but still the list stays NULL (the console output shows the correct output).

Comment: After some more fiddling, adding the model works, BUT i had to remove all JSON.stringify references, with this line MVC just does not accept the list.

Comment: Actually I was cheering too much, it happens that I do see all rows coming in the array, but the values are not filled! This is getting a bit annoying now..

Comment: I have this same problem.  It create list items, but the property values of each item are the default value(null/0).  I believe it has something to do with the encoding `Rates%5b0%5d.Number=2&Rates%5b0%5d.Amount=876876`.  Did you ever work through this?

Answer (score 6):

Try changing your controller action to (I'm assuming here that Specification is a model representing the JSON you're trying to post):

```
public Boolean Save(Int32 productId, List<Specification> specifications)
```

And then change these things in your JS:

```
var params = {
    'productId': productId,
    'specifications': []
};

params.specifications.add(specification);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Admin/Product/Save/",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function () { alert('done'); }
});
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work, it gives me an error 500: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Boolean Save(Int32, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.Specification])' in 'Areas.Admin.Controllers.ProductController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.<br>Parameter name: parameters

Comment: I edited my answer to include contentType: 'application/json'. Try adding that to your AJAX call. I think it will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery `.ajax()` converts the JSON object to a collection of key value pairs in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.  You can read a good explanation of this in the blog post and comments of [POSTing JSON Data to MVC Controllers](http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2010/04/16/posting_json_data_to_mvc_controllers.aspx)

So, You should either create a custom ModelBinder or put `FormCollection form` as the parameter instead of `Object[]`.  The [`FormCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx) will give you a `NameValueCollection` of the Form's values that also implements `IValueProvider`.  You can loop through the collection and all your data will be there.

Comment: Not possible because the fields are dynamic, not static.

Comment: @rogier21, what is not possible?  Regardless of how the fields are generated, all the POST submitted values will be in the FormCollection

Comment: That is what I thought, but tested it a few times and I did not get the values that I generated by myself.

Comment: @Rogier21, I have trouble believing that.  Can you please post the full code and the result of looping through the keys in the `FormCollection`?