# Form Encoded Javascript int[] not Picked up By Model Binder

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Last night I tried to put together something that I have had working since MVC2.

Given the following class:

```
public class RouteSaveViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string DepartureDate { get; set; }
    public string ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    public List<int> LocationIds { get; set; }
}
```

...and the action below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult SaveRoute(RouteSaveViewModel route)
    {
        // yada yada
        return SomethingShiny();
    }
```

I would like to pass in the data using a $.ajax or $.post. The form is multi-step to collect data from the user and submit it.  The code I use to build the location Ids up is this:

```
        var routeStopIds = [];
        $(".route-stop").each(function(){
            routeStopIds.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
        });
```

I have verified that there the ids I expect are in this array through in-browser dev tools and fiddler. Finally, to submit the data, I'm mapping out the object as I've done in previous MVC builds:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: postUrl,
            data: {
                Title: $("#route-title").val(),
                Comments: $("#route-description").val(),
                DepartureDate: depDate,
                ArrivalDate: arrDate,
                LocationIds: routeStopIds                    
            },
            dataType: 'JSON'
        });
```

What I'm seeing is that *all* data - except the `LocationIds` param is populated.  I have also tried to submit just the `routeStopIds` array to a modified `SaveRoute` that only accepts a `List<int>` and that doesn't appear to be working either.  Either way, `LocationIds` is null, though there is a form-encoded value in the form parameters on the request.

```
{LocationIds%5b%5d=44&LocationIds%5b%5d=4&LocationIds%5b%5d=2}
```

...and yet the HttpValueCollection is just `LocationIds[]`, an empty array.

So, am I missing something obvious?  Maybe not-so-obvious?  How do I get the array to be picked up by model binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that part where I said I had it working since MVC2?  Yeah, that was here:
[Advanced Model Binding](http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.ca/2010/05/aspnet-mvc-and-jquery-part-4-advanced.html)  In that post I explicitly mentioned the following:

> Note: In order to make the results of the array compatible with the
>   binding mechanism in ASP.NET MVC (as at MVC 2.0) we need to use the
>   ‘traditional’ setting in $.ajax().

Modifying the ajax call to include this setting was the fix. All is right as rain and soft woolen kittens. Or mittens or whatever.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: postUrl,
            traditional: true, // <----- here be kittens
            data: {

                Title: $("#route-title").val(),
                Comments: $("#route-description").val(),
                DepartureDate: depDate,
                ArrivalDate: arrDate,
                LocationIds: routeStopIds 
            },
            dataType: 'JSON'
        });
```