# Sending a LIST of JSON object from javascript to MVC action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

In my javascript i make a JSON like object with two properties : ControllerName and WordNumber and add them to an Array.

```
function TestN() {
                var list = new Array();


            $("*[wordNum]").each(function ()
            {
                var endRes = {
                    ControllerName: this.id,
                    WordNumber: this.getAttribute("wordNum")
                };

                list.push(endRes);


            });


            jQuery.ajax({
                url:' @Url.Action("Translate")' ,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { List : JSON.stringify(list) }
,
                traditional: true

            })
        }
    </script>
```

In .net I've got this class with the same properties :

```
public class TranslateModel
    {
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public string WordNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my action+

```
 public ActionResult Translate(ICollection<TranslateModel> List)
        { return View(); }
```

As you may suppose the List property in  Translate Action  is empty (model binding doesn't work);

Comment: try posting without JSON.stringify, just put the raw list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you used JSON.stringify(list), it send string value to the controller action, instead of the object.

there are two approaches
1) either you send string to controller's action and Deserialize  string to object and use.

2) create the model property as array of list and send that model to controller action without using JSON.stringify.

here are two links that may help you.

--approach-1

[ASP.NET MVC 4 JSON Binding to the View Model - Nested object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373202/asp-net-mvc-4-json-binding-to-the-view-model-nested-object-error)

--approach-2
[Passing json list to MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405543/passing-json-list-to-mvc-3)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your AJAX function to this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: ' @Url.Action("Translate")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'List': list }),
    traditional: true
});
```